# continuar executando quando der duplicate key, como proceder?

Tags: java

tenho 9 testes em cada procedimento, mas em algum momento o cara salvou um desses teste em nulo, mas é possível ele salvar nulo, pois pode ser que esses teste não seja aplicável para aquela situação... Mas por algum motivo ele não preencheu um teste que deveria estar preenchido e acabou salvando sem esse teste. Para corrigir essa situação, eu criei uma nova tabela em que ela salva todos os testes, mas se o código do teste estiver já salvo, ela não vai substituir, mas caso ele não esteja nessa tabela, ele irá salvar. Mas surgiu um problema, se o primeiro teste já estiver na tabela de testes, ele já da duplicate key e nem tenta salvar os outros.. alguém sabe me dizer como faço para que ele, continue testando os outros teste para ver se ele existe ou não?

Exemplificando: ao dar duplicate key, ele continuar o código e não parar

Segue o código:

```
       int p = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Você deseja realmente salvar?", "Salvar", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (p
                == 0) {
            String resultado_numerico = new String();
            String resultado_texto = new String();
            String observacao = new String();
            String aprovado = new String();
            try {
                Class.forName(Auxiliar.AcessoBanco.getDriver());
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Auxiliar.AcessoBanco.getUrl(), Auxiliar.AcessoBanco.getUser(), Auxiliar.AcessoBanco.getPass());
                for (int i = 0; i < CadresultadoTabela.getRowCount(); i++) {

                    if ((resultado_numerico.equals("") || resultado_texto.equals("")) && aprovado.equals("")) {

                        java.util.Date currentDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime();
                        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                        String dateString = df.format(currentDate);

                        java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                        String timeString = sdf.format(d);
                        String value0 = timeString;
                        String values = dateString;
                        String sql = "INSERT INTO Resultado (ORDEM,LINHA,LINHA_TIPO,LINHA_SETOR,RCPERFIL,BPCS,"
                                + "DPERFIL,PROJETO,OEM,N_DESENHO,N_PLANO,OPERACAO,EQUIPAMENTO,DTESTE,"
                                + "RCOMPLEMENTO,RCTESTE,ESPEC_MIN,ESPEC_MAX,ESPEC_UNID,ESPEC_TEXTO,REFERENCIA,"
                                + "FREQUENCIA,FREQ_UNID,PRODUTO,ORIGEM,RTIPO,ESPECIFICACAO,FREQ_TEXTO,LAB,"
                                + "ENCONTRADO,ENCONT_TEXTO,OBS,APROVADO,DATA,HORA,REGISTRO,N_OP,BATCH,N_ETIQUETA,DATAM) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,'" + values + " " + value0 + "')";
                        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

//                System.out.println();
                        int Ordem = Integer.parseInt(CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());//1
                        String Linha = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());//2
                        String Linha_Tipo = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());//3
                        String Setor = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());//4
                        int Perfil = Integer.parseInt(CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 5).toString());//5
                        String Bpcs = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());//6
                        String Desc_Perfil = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 7).toString());//7
                        String Projeto = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 8).toString());//8
                        String OEM = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 9).toString());//9
                        String Nº_Desenho = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 10).toString());//10
                        String Nº_Plano = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 11).toString());//11
                        String Operação = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 12).toString());//12
                        String Equipamento = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 13).toString());//13
                        String Desc_Teste = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 14).toString());//14
                        String Complemento = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 15).toString());//15
                        String Cod_Teste = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 16).toString());//16
                        float Espec_Min = Float.parseFloat(CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 17).toString());//17
                        float Espec_Max = Float.parseFloat(CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 18).toString());//18
                        String Espec_Unid = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 19).toString());//19
                        String Espec_Texto = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 20).toString());//20
                        String Referência = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 21).toString());//21
                        int Frequência = Integer.parseInt(CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 22).toString());//22
                        String Freq_Unid = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 23).toString());//23
                        String Produto = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 24).toString());//24
                        String Origem = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 25).toString());//25
                        String Tipo = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 26).toString());//26
                        String Especificação = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 27).toString());//27
                        String Freq_Texto = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 28).toString());//28
                        String Laboratorio = (CadresultadoTabela.getValueAt(i, 29).toString());//29
                        String Resultado_Numerico = resultado_numerico;//30
                        String Resultado_Texto = resultado_texto;//31
                        String Observação = observacao;//32
                        String Aprovado = aprovado;//33

                        pst.setInt(1, Ordem);//1
                        pst.setString(2, Linha);//2
                        pst.setString(3, Linha_Tipo);//3
                        pst.setString(4, Setor);//4
                        pst.setInt(5, Perfil);//5
                        pst.setString(6, Bpcs);//6
                        pst.setString(7, Desc_Perfil);//7
                        pst.setString(8, Projeto);//8
                        pst.setString(9, OEM);//9
                        pst.setString(10, Nº_Desenho);//10
                        pst.setString(11, Nº_Plano);//11
                        pst.setString(12, Operação);//12
                        pst.setString(13, Equipamento);//13
                        pst.setString(14, Desc_Teste);//14
                        pst.setString(15, Complemento);//15
                        pst.setString(16, Cod_Teste);//16
                        pst.setFloat(17, Espec_Min);//17
                        pst.setFloat(18, Espec_Max);//18
                        pst.setString(19, Espec_Unid);//19
                        pst.setString(20, Espec_Texto);//20
                        pst.setString(21, Referência);//21
                        pst.setInt(22, Frequência);//22
                        pst.setString(23, Freq_Unid);//23
                        pst.setString(24, Produto);//24
                        pst.setString(25, Origem);//25
                        pst.setString(26, Tipo);//26
                        pst.setString(27, Especificação);//27
                        pst.setString(28, Freq_Texto);//28
                        pst.setString(29, Laboratorio);//29
                        pst.setString(30, Resultado_Numerico);//30
                        pst.setString(31, Resultado_Texto);//31
                        pst.setString(32, Observação);//32
                        pst.setString(33, Aprovado);//33

                        pst.setString(34, txt_data.getText());
                        pst.setString(35, txt_hora.getText());
                        pst.setString(36, txt_registro.getText());
                        pst.setString(37, txt_operacao.getText());
                        pst.setString(38, txt_batch.getText());
                        pst.setString(39, txt_N_Etiqueta.getText());

                        pst.executeUpdate();

                    }

                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Salvo com sucesso!");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
```

Comment: Qual banco que você está usando? Tenta adicionar ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING no final da claúsula INSERT